# How can I write this pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I'm currently working on a class that extracts certain letters from a huge text file, and I can't seem to make a proper pattern for it to track down what I want.
The Pattern I'm using is :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'[A-Z ]'|'[.]'");
```

When searching through something like this :('L','O','','B','I')
, my Matcher returns 'L''O''B'I'(I am using it to store every match in a StringBuilder), but does not return the space, and I need it to.

I apologize for any presentation flaws, but I'm still getting used to asking questions here.

EDIT:
what I want is to get the answer for a crossword puzzle. I have a class that gets the code from the crossword puzzle and saves it in a text file. After that, I want to run this code in order to get the answers , which are organised like this:

```
L[0] = new Array('S','O','L','O','M','I','L','L','O','','B','I','B','L','I','O','','C','A','O');
L[1] = new Array('A','R','T','R','O','S','E','','D','I','N','A','M','I','T','E','','E','U','');
L[2] = new Array('R','C','P','','R','I','C','A','','','','','','','','','','','','');
L[3] = new Array('R','A','','','A','S','A','','A','N','O','R','M','L','','P','U','T','I','N');
L[4] = new Array('O','','','','T','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','');
L[5] = new Array('','','','','O','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','');
```

I need the spaces in order to separate one answer from another , and currently the output my class returns is

```
SOLOMILLOBIBLIOCAOARTROSEDINAMITEEURCPRICARAASAANORMLPUTINOTO`
```

after I removed all the extra unwanted symbols.
What I need it to return is:

```
SOLOMILLO BIBLIO CAO ARTROSE DINAMITE EU RCP RICA RA ASA ANORML PUTIN O T O
```

Comment: Maybe you can better define what it is you're trying to achieve? _certain letters_ is pretty vague.

Comment: Can you show us how you are using this pattern? BTW `'[A-Z ]'|'[.]'` can be rewritten into probably more readable `'[A-Z .]'`. Also input from your question doesn't seem to have any space surrounded with `'`.

Comment: Can you provide some example text and your expected result?

Comment: Your string has a `''`, an empty string inside `''`. If you need to also extract empty strings, you can use a `?` quantifier (0 or 1 times) with `[A-Z .]` character class: `"'[A-Z .]?'"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- replace empty `''` with `' '` (with space inside)`
- add all characters surrounded by `'` (including space) to StringBuilder (you seem to already have this step, also `'([A-Z ])'` should probably be fine here).
- convert builder to string
- trim to remove spaces at start and end
- replace two or more spaces with one space (`replaceAll("\\s{2,}"," ")` can be useful).

If you want to also add spaces to separate results from each lines consider parsing each line separately and add space after each parsed line.

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/u17jlk)**

Comment: Thank you , now it's working , but apparently the way I'm removing the unwanted characters is also removing spaces. I' m removing them like this: String [] list=s.split("[']") . any idea how to make spaces also appear?

Comment: @Azerogg I am not quite sure what you want to achieve with this split. Anyway I updated my answer with link to code example.

Comment: I apologize, I hadn't noticed it before.Thank you.

Comment: @Azerogg There is nothing to apologize for :) I placed that link after your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are a bit confused with what you are trying to look for.  On one hand, you want to look for A-Z or a space.  On the other, you want to look for *any* character.  Your second part of the condition encompasses the first.  You could use the following to get what you are after:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'.*?'");
```